# Query two separate fields from one field in a table

Tags: ms-access

I have a ms access database with two tables I am concerned with.

```
Table 1
       ...[field 1] "Name" text
       ...[field 2] "IDBorn" number
       ...[field 3] "IDDied" number
Table 2
       ...[field 1] "IDDate"  number
       ...[field 2] "dtISO"   text of date
```

"IDBorn" and "IDDied" are related to "IDDate"

My question.  Can I query (in one query) to get

```
...[field 1] "Name"  text
...[field 2] "Born On" text of born on date
...[field 3] "Died On" text of died on date
```

I have not been able to get a successful UNION query to work.  Is that the way to go?

Comment: Why not store date directly in the database in columns `IDBorn` and `IDDied`

Comment: Why do you have text of date? This is an easy formatting issue.

Comment: UNION is for adding Rows to the bottom of an existing table/dataset.
JOIN is used for adding Columns to a table/dataset.

Answer (score 1):

your need create two inner join for each field

```
select Name, T1A.IDBorn, T1B.IDDied 
from [Table 2] T2
inner join [Table 1] T1A
    on T2.IDDate = T1A.IDBorn
inner join [Table 1] T1B
    on T2.IDDate = T1B.IDDied
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: Lots of people are born on the same day.

Comment: Use INNER JOIN, got it.

Answer (score 0):

While yes this is a bad example of where you want to have a lookup table for some data in your main table (You should just use the date field), Jorge Londoño's answer above is the correct way to query it.

You can also Open the table in design view. Select the field "IDBorn" Click on the Lookup tab in properties.

Display Control = "Combo Box".

Row Source Type = "Table/Query".

Row Source =

```
SELECT T1A.IDBorn,Name 
FROM [Table 2] T2 INNER JOIN [Table 1] T1A  on T2.IDDate = T1A.IDBorn
```

Bound column = "1"

Column Count = "2"

Column Width = "0;20"

This will show the actual value instead of the lookup value. Then depending on what you are doing with the table you may not have to do this query every time you want to get the data out of the table.